# Does anyone know how to capture the mouse in Flex/Flash Air application?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

Does someone know how to capture the mouse in an air application. I know its possible because the flex scrollbar captures the mouse. I want to replicate the scrollbar's mouse capture.

**Try this in a flex/air application window:**

```
<s:Scroller height="500" width="300">
    <s:VGroup>
        <s:Rect width="100%" height="2000">
            <s:fill>
                <s:SolidColor color="#ffcc00"/>
            </s:fill>
        </s:Rect>
    </s:VGroup>
</s:Scroller>
```

If you press and hold the scrollbar handle and drag outside, even outside the window, the scrollbar still works. It wont lose focus. So it is capturing the mouse.

what I want:

- Mouse and touch capture. (Even outside the window while still pressing down the button or touch point)

Comment: Have you tried implementing this the naive way? To my recollection it works automatically - you keep getting MouseMove events even outside the stage, so long as a drag operation is in progress. It might depending on also having registered for, say, MouseDown or DragStart, but there shouldn't be any magic to it.

Comment: I'm not actually trying to drag an object, I want to implement panning. Like any touch device when you want to scroll down. Do you know of something I could use? I tried startDrag but it moves the entire container Im using. It sort of captures the mouse, no events are fired if the mouse is outside the window but the dragging resumes when the mouse returns to the window.

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing this. This is in a browser, right? Are you on a touch device? (Often on devices the browser eats drag events before they get to Flash except in certain situations, like fullscreen mode.)
Anyway I'll write a proper answer with some test code, as I believe this should just work (meaning your problem may be elsewhere).

Comment: Not sure I follow what you're trying to do.  Doesn't scroller already do that for you?

Comment: I'm not actually in a mobile device, Im in a windows slate, or windows with touch screen. I need both mouse and touch. Also this is an AIR application not browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least on desktops using a mouse, this should Just Work as far as I know. For example:

```
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var t:TextField = new TextField();
stage.addChild(t);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouse);

function onMouse( e:MouseEvent ) {
    t.text = e.stageX +", "+ e.stageY;
}
```

For me, events show up in the text field both when the mouse is inside the Flash area, and when you click inside Flash and drag outside. So if you're having problems, my guess is that it might be related to the components you're using or how your content is structured (e.g. what object you're registering for events on, etc.). But there isn't any special way of getting mouse events to continue when the user drags out of the Flash rectangle.

(Note that touch devices may be a different situation - often their browsers eat pan gestures before they get to Flash except in fullscreen mode, or sometimes they give Flash drag events when Flash is "zoomed in" (by double-tapping). Your mileage may vary with different browsers on different devices..)

Comment: This is actually a windows with touch screen (slate pc or touchscreen). Does your example work in an air application? For example you start a drag and drop operation and move the mouse outside the window while still pressing the mouse?

Comment: It works fine in AIR apps on the PC. I don't know about slates as I've never used one, but unless the OS is eating the events like I described, it should work the same way. Incidentally, by default touch events are translated into mouse events, so you should get them free too. (You have to flip some switches before you get TouchEvents, even if the app is running on a touch device.)

Comment: I did some tests, it works if I add the listener to the stage and click and drag outside of the window. Events will come to the stage. So if I click the stage and keep the button pressed, the stage is capturing the mouse. It wont work for a button though. If I click and drag outside the button it wont capture the mouse so no events will come to it.

Comment: Ill have to add the event listener to the stage, not my object or container. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't get any information that would be meaningful for you.  I understand what you're trying to accomplish, and yes, you're right that scroll bars have some black magic to them in that if you begin a drag it will continue to scroll even if the mouse is out of the range of the player.

I ran some tests on trying to listen into events and came up empty handed.  The player itself must get them but they aren't exposed in anyway that I can find.

So, I thought about creating a more or less hidden scroll component (or set of them) that would capture the click to and start the drag event.  Somewhat a hack, but cool idea...

Then you could poll the current scroll position to make a guess at where the mouse is (outside of the window) with a set of horiz and vert scrollers.  You CAN do this, however, the issue comes that the scroller position values will have maximum limits based on their native size.  This means that you'll be left with gaps on where the mouse is.  So you could knowhow far up or down the Y axis mouse is positioned on the screen, even if it is outside far the the left or right (X axis) of the appliction (I was on a second monitor for example), BUT you will not know where it exists on the X axis, and you would only know the Y as it relates to the application size (not above or below where it exists on the screen elsewhere).

Here's an image of what you could capture with this trick / hack :
[image]

So yes, you could do a polling type of method like I described, but, you would only get those coordinates.

Ultimately, it isn't very helpful because you need to expand the boundries of the scroll rect (or app) to fully capture where the mouse is - thus you would expand it to the full size of the screen, and could just use normal events.  This is particularly true of the negative boundries (left or above app).

What I havent tried is creating a large container positioned outside the main app window and applying a scroller to it.  If you did this you could potentially make it work:

[image]

It was an interesting concept, clever - definitely not supported functionality.  :P~

Comment: I also thought about putting a hidden scrollbar on top of the content to handle the scrolling, but I also want to be able to click on objects inside the area im panning when I just tap or click (without dragging)

Comment: I assure you there is no black magic in flex scrollbars, They use the same events as you do. The framework is open source, you can check if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I use for this purpose:

```
import flash.display.InteractiveObject;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class Dragger
{
    private var target:InteractiveObject;
    private var mouseDownPoint:Point;
    private var originalPosition:Point;

    public function Dragger(target:InteractiveObject)
    {
        this.target = target;
        target.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onMouseDown);
    }

    private function onMouseDown(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        mouseDownPoint = new Point(event.stageX, event.stageY);
        originalPosition = new Point(target.x, target.y);
        event.stopPropagation();

        target.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
        target.stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
    } 
    private function onMouseUp(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        onMouseMove(event);
        mouseDownPoint = null;
        event.stopPropagation();
        target.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, onMouseMove);
        target.stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onMouseUp);
    } 
    private function onMouseMove(event:MouseEvent):void
    {
        if (!mouseDownPoint) return;
        target.x = originalPosition.x + event.stageX - mouseDownPoint.x;
        target.y = originalPosition.y + event.stageY - mouseDownPoint.y;
        event.updateAfterEvent();               
        event.stopPropagation();
    } 
}
```

To use, simply do new Dragger(your_object).